# Readonly = true on Lightning input changes the padding -left

Tags: lightning-web-components

If the lightning-input field is not read only the default padding left is 2rem.  Once it is on readonly the padding left is changed to .75rem resulting to this behavior.

is there a way to target the css of that one programatically?
[image]

this that I have tried ,

1. I tried to disable the lightning-input via CSS  by putting user-input : none,
2. I tried targetting via input:read-only but it resizes the whole textfield not just the inside part of it (I guess I am trying to target the wrong element)
3. I have tried to applying dynamic class , still no luck.

any thoughts about this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to [shadow DOM](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_dom) you cannot target those elements, but you can customize it via [styling hooks](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/platforms/lightning/styling-hooks/).
Please note that padding-left is setted using [CSS var function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/var()), that get two parameters: a custom property (`--lwc-spacingSmall` in this case) and a fallback value. In a parent component you can set the custom property in order to customize your CSS.

I would give a custom css class (i.e. `p-left-large`) to the lightning-input element in order to customize the padding only for that one in the css file.

**CSS:**

```
:host .p-left-large {
    --lwc-spacingSmall: 2rem;
}
```

Comment: That worked like a charm, Thank you so much!